# Why is there voting when all questions must be directly answerable with facts?

Tags: discussion

The [most voted question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6/exercises-for-a-programmer-sitting-by-the-pc-all-day) on this site is locked because its opinion bait. Why vote at all if questions must be answerable with a short blurb of facts?

What is the value or lure of seeing or voting on the answers 4, 5, or 2 to the question of "1 + 2 = " ? That is basically how the site is currently set up which results in the most voted question becomes closed. Google is already answering these types of questions automatically. It doesn't take many answers or much research to come to a good solution for these types of questions.

The original site was for software questions where there is no single factually correct answer and is normally answerable with many good and bad solutions of which some may even be incorrect. With each input/answer you get a partial solution that when put together can be a powerful and efficient solution.

That doesnt sound like a model for simple fact based question and answer blurbs. Instead sounds like opinion bait that uses opinions (ie votes) to decide which ones are the best. Whats up with that?

BTW, the most useful answer I got here was an opinion bait question that I thought would be closed for sure :)

Answer (score 3):

Making a case and supporting it is not (necessarily) the same as answering with a "short blurb of facts." Fitness tends to attract all sorts of psuedo-science, heresay, and hocus-pocus, and it's important to separate that from thoughtful problem solving.

I don't think your arithmetic problem is representative, even as a metaphor. The human body is at best a only partially-understood system, and similarly to programming challenges there are often multiple ways to accomplish a goal, each with their own tradeoffs and side effects. However, solutions do need to be based on science and reasonable principles, rather than snake oil and uninformed opinions.

Comment: Bro, it's just curls+supplements for sick gainz.

Comment: Don't forget quality mirror time, brah

Comment: Shouldn't votes separate psuedo-science and baseless opinions from thoughtful problem solving instead of closing a question? Is there some sort of harm in a question getting too many answers?

Comment: @Jason Absolutely votes should separate the poor answers (and questions) from the good ones. In the case of this particular question, I believe it was closed because it was very broad along the lines of, and yes I'm exaggerating a bit, "how do I program computers"? Note that questions can be re-opened with votes.

Comment: @Jason as far as general philosophy on what does and doesn't construe a constructive question - you might have better luck taking that to the main SE meta, as I don't think we are implementing any unique deviations from that here (at least not on purpose).

Comment: @Greg Im not really trying to take on that with SE meta. I just think there is a good specific point in that question about sitting in a fixed position all day long. More than just the lack of exercise. I usually cant run the next day after doing a hard run and sitting for +8 hours, but can when not working.

Comment: @Jason agree re sitting in fixed position, FWIW. I suspect the question is somewhat ambiguous to some though - this could be about eye strain, carpal tunnel etc. But... seems to me 5 community votes could re-open it.

Answer (score -3):

Google doesnt own SE and so their software engineers have been sabotaging the site in order to manipulate it into generating answers for their search engine that is a step above the question "1 + 2 =".

Thereby Google software engineers finally get a 3 hour lunch instead of just two hours. Though its an unofficial victory to the struggle of extending their lunchtime they dont mind because its a pretty awesome hack.

If it wasnt a good hack then it'd be Microsoft engineers behind this somehow...

Comment: Um, what? How is this connected to a fitness site?

Comment: @Greg How cant you see the point?

Comment: I'm being thick on purpose because I just don't have it in me to address a conspiracy theory about Google engineers trying to sabotage SE.

Comment: @Greg I was highlighting the point of the question by pointing out that Google is already taking up that niche... no one has got a sense of humor anymore... oh this isnt a blog...